# Fail to target a instance inside a MC in an Array

Tags: actionscript-3, arrays

I can't trace whats inside holderMC, and its content. What's wrong here?

```
  instance.text="something"
   holderMC.addChild(instance)
   anArray.push(holderMC)
   addChild(holderMC)

   trace(anArray[anArray.length-1].instance.text);
```

returned undefined.

Comment: what do you get from:
trace (anArray[anArray.length-1].instance);
trace (anArray[anArray.length-1]);
trace (anArray.length);
trace (anArray);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
instance.text="something"
instance.name = "instance"
holderMC.addChild(instance)
anArray.push(holderMC)
addChild(holderMC)

trace(anArray[anArray.length-1].getChildByName("instance").text);
```

Comment: yes or:
trace(anArray[anArray.length-1].getChildAt(0).text); //will be 0 if its the only other object

Comment: should be my side problem cause the text is define from somewhere else. but this helps too. thanx!

Answer (score 0):

This should definitely work:

```
instance.text="something";
holderMC.addChild(instance);
anArray.push(holderMC);
addChild(holderMC);

trace("instance.text: " + instance.text);
trace("holderMC.instance: " + holderMC.getChildAt(holderMC.numChildren - 1));
trace("holderMC.instance.text : " + (holderMC.getChildAt(holderMC.numChildren - 1)as TextField).text);
```

You need to cast the Child to TextField, because it getChild... returns a DisplayObject.

This is all assuming that instance is a TextField or another component with a text property.